# How to deploy to Herouku through Travis CI without building the project twice?

Tags: java, heroku, travis-ci, jhipster

I have a JHipster project I want to build through Travis CI and then deploy to Heroku. However, even if Travis CI passes the build, it commits the whole code to Heroku and then Heroku tries to build the whole project again, defeating the purpose of having Travis CI in the middle.

Is there a way to build my project with Travis CI and then just deploy the build WAR to Heroku?

Given the fact that JHipster uses Spring Boot, I would only need the WAR to run the application.

Here is my .travis.yml files:

```
language:
- java
jdk:
  - oraclejdk8
sudo: false
env:
  - MAVEN_CUSTOM_OPTS="-Pprod,heroku -DskipTests"
before_install:
- npm install -g npm
- rm -fr /home/travis/.npm/
- npm cache clean -g
- npm install grunt-cli -g
- npm install
install:
- mvn package -Pprod -DskipTests 
script: true
notifications:
  webhooks:
    on_success: change
    on_failure: always
    on_start: false
deploy:
  provider: heroku
  api_key:
    secure: [key]
  skip_cleanup: true
```

Also, if there is another way to deploy a Spring Boot application through this process, it would be great.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can install the [heroku-deploy](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-deploy) plugin on Travis CI and deploy the same way you [deploy to Heroku locally](http://jhipster.github.io/heroku/).

In fact, this is what the heroku-deploy plugin does to test itself, so you can use it as an example. The [setup script](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-deploy/blob/master/etc/travis-setup.sh) downloads the Ubuntu installer for the toolbelt from: https://toolbelt.heroku.com/install-ubuntu.sh

Then you'll only need to install the plugin with this command in your setup script:

```
heroku plugins:install https://github.com/heroku/heroku-deploy
```

And set your API key as a secure variable in the `.travis.yml`